# Installation of plugin to Jenkins DSL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

How I can create Jenkins job via Jenkins DSL using the custom plugin?
I have tried to implement WebHook Plugin: https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin
But via DSL I receiving an error that genericTrigger class does not exist.

> Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.triggers.TriggerContext.GenericTrigger()
>   is applicable for argument types:
>   (script$_run_closure2$_closure5$_closure11) values:
>   [script$_run_closure2$_closure5$_closure11@7f132176]

I have tried to add this plugin to gradlew dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins:generic-webhook-trigger:1.4'
}
```

But still the same error.
How I correct import them? I have tried to clone from github these classes, but dependencies required other ones, external.
How to correct do this?

P.S. Plugin has been installed on Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

The built-in DSL from the JobDSL plugin does not offer a support for all possible plugins available on Jenkins.

However, they do provide 2 additional ways to configure "non-supported" plugins:

1. Dynamic DSL
2. The Configure Block

The first one, the Dynamic DSL, looks very much on the built-in DSL. To understand if the plugin supports it, the easiest way is to checkout the API viewer on **your** jenkins instance (https://[your_jenkins_domain]/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html)

Search for your plugin and if it supports it, you'll see something like the following which shows a dynamic dsl for the slack notification plugin:

[image: dynamic-dsl-example]

Find more information on the Dynamic DSL [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Dynamic-DSL).

If it's not supported by the Dynamic DSL, then you can still configure it through the "The Configure Block". This part is a bit harder as it requires to parse XML with Groovy. But everything is nicely explained in [their documentation too](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block).

Finally, there are slides about [Automating Jenkins](https://speakerdeck.com/tonivdv/jenkins-automation?slide=35). You'll find an example for both cases. And a [blog post](https://www.devexp.eu/2014/10/26/use-unsupported-jenkins-plugins-with-jenkins-dsl/) about the Configure Block which should still be applicable.